# Cannot connect to webpage using selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, webdriver, webdriverwait

I am trying to connect to the particular webpage but it does not click on `Login` button:

```
browser.get('https://www.tsago.gr/eshop/account')
print('Browser Opened')
username = browser.find_element_by_id('email')
username.send_keys(email)
password = browser.find_element_by_id('password')

password.send_keys(pwd)
time.sleep(2)
sing_in = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@class="btn btn-primary"]')
sing_in.click()
print('Login Clicked')
```

I have tried find element by css, by name etc but I dont know why is not clicking on the button in order to login

The html part is the following

```
<div class="span3 float-right" style="float:right;">                                   
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Connect</button>
</div>
```

The username and password are written and they are correct

Comment: Try `sing_in = browser.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@type="submit"]')`

Comment: No nothing.. is there a way to click Enter by code? instead by clicking button? maybe it needs focus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you were pretty close. Perhaps *Cookies Message Bar* was the obstacle and you can either *accept the cookies* or scroll the *Connect* button into view and you can use the following solution:

- Code Block:

  ```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

  options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
  options.add_argument("start-maximized")
  options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
  # options.add_argument('disable-infobars')
  browser = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Utility\BrowserDrivers\chromedriver.exe')
  browser.get('https://www.tsago.gr/eshop/account')
  print('Browser Opened')
  WebDriverWait(browser, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input#email[name='email']"))).send_keys("Nikos")
  browser.find_element_by_css_selector("input#password[name='password']").send_keys("Nikos")
  browser.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,250)", "");
  browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div.control-group div.span3 button.btn.btn-primary").click()
  print('Login Clicked')
  ```
- Console Output:

  ```
  Browser Opened
  Login Clicked
  ```
- Browser Snapshot:

[image: cookies]

Answer (score 0):

The following css Selector should uniquely identify the button you are looking for:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.span3.float-right > button')
```

Answer (score 0):

this is working for me:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector('div.span3 > button[type="submit"]').click()
```

generally, you should make sure you identify the correct element before coding. to do so - use devTools (f12 on chrome/firefox), and run your query in the 'console' tab

for xpath identification **try $x**, i.e: `$x('//button[@type="submit"]')`.

for css selector **use $$** like so : `$$("div.someClass#someID")`

you can than hover over the results and the found elements would highlight

**edit**:
i noticed you had trouble with the css option, you can allso try

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[contains(@class,"span3")]/button[contains(@class,"btn-primary")]")
```